# How can I call ActiveX from SAP?

Tags: activex, abap, ole

I have a custom ActiveX control that I would like to Call from SAP.

In this case I cannot use PI, what other options do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See program **SAPRDEMO_ACTIVEX_INTEGRATION** as an example.

```
 DATA: control       TYPE REF TO i_oi_container_control, 
      ocx_document  TYPE REF TO i_oi_document_proxy,
      has_activex   TYPE flag,
      retcode       TYPE soi_ret_string,
      doc_handle    TYPE cntl_handle,
      document_type TYPE soi_document_type VALUE 'SAPActiveXDoc.Example1'.

"Test whether activeX is supported"
CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_HAS_ACTIVEX'
    IMPORTING return  = has_activex.
CHECK NOT has_activex IS INITIAL.

CALL METHOD control->init_control
       EXPORTING r3_application_name      = 'R/3 Basis'
                 inplace_enabled          = 'X'
                 register_on_close_event  = 'X'
                 register_on_custom_event = 'X'
                 parent                   = cl_gui_container=>default_screen
       IMPORTING retcode                  = retcode.

CALL METHOD control->get_document_proxy
       EXPORTING document_type  = document_type
       IMPORTING document_proxy = oxc_document
                 retcode        = retcode.

CALL METHOD oxc_document->open_activex_document
       IMPORTING retcode = retcode.

CALL METHOD ocx_document->get_document_handle
       IMPORTING handle  = doc_handle
                 retcode = retcode.

CALL FUNCTION 'CONTROL_CALL_METHOD'
       EXPORTING h_control = doc_handle
                 method    = 'MyMethod'
                 p_count   = 0.

CALL METHOD ocx_document->clsoe_activex_document
       IMPORTING retcode = retcode.
```

I've stripped out the screen processing & error handling of the example program in order to give an overview of main calls that are needed.